# Security issues when sending POST request wih CakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have view that uses jQuery to send POST data to my controller, but it's failing and I get the following error:

```
The request has been black-holed 
The requested address'/settings/submit_bank_info' was not found on this server.
```

The only way I can get it to work is by removing the security in that controller all together.

Here's the before filter of the controller in question

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('help','submit_bank_info');
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';
}
```

If saw this on cake's documentation

> When using the Security Component you must use the FormHelper to
>   create your forms. In addition, you must not override any of the
>   fields’ “name” attributes. The Security Component looks for certain
>   indicators that are created and managed by the FormHelper (especially
>   those created in create() and end()). Dynamically altering the fields
>   that are submitted in a POST request (e.g. disabling, deleting or
>   creating new fields via JavaScript) is likely to trigger a
>   black-holing of the request. See the $validatePost or $disabledFields
>   configuration parameters.

I'm using version 2.3.8. Is there some way that I can just disable it for that action so I can keep the security component for the other actions?

Comment: does /settings/help or does /help work?

Comment: Yes, but those aren't javascript/jquery based forms. They're built with the form helper. I had to use javascript/jquery for the "submit_bank_info" for a couple reasons. I'm using Balanced Payments card processing.

Answer (score 2):

try to stop the jQuery and post the form and use firebug to track which hidden data CakePHP is sending with the form, as their documentation they send hidden data to prevent CSRF attack.

> The csrfExpires property can be any value that is compatible with
>   strtotime(). By default the FormHelper will add a data[_Token][key]
>   containing the CSRF token to every form when the component is enabled.

Try to capture the hidden fields and send it along with your jquery request.

**UPDATE**

Also try to generate the form using CakePHP it will generate data[_Token][fields] and data[_Token][unlocked] hidden fields with their keys:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('formA',array('id'=>'formA'));
    echo $this->Form->input('inputA');
    echo $this->Form->submit();
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

this will generate

```
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="randomValue"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="randomValue"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][unlocked]" value=""/>
```

In ur JQuery ajax request `serialize()` the form and send it.